# Stupid question... where is the logout button???

Tags: support

The Chat is telling me I need to login to chat, and when I go to login from there it tells me the meta data is old and to login to any stack exchange site to update it. But I can't login because I'm already logged in and cannot find the logout button....

Comment: "There's no way out of here 
when you come in you're in for good..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They removed it recently from the main banner. It's now on your main site profile page. There's 3 links: edit | add openid | log out.

meta.SO question - [Logout link now missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80610/154388)

Comment: Thank you. I checked my profile page but didn't realize I had to be viewing the profile page of my main user, not the Programmers one.

Comment: Well, it turns out that @Rachel asked the opposite of a stupid question. The answer was actually quite unintuitive.

Comment: @Adam: I didn't use the link much before they changed it, and I was surprised too. I think I'd prefer it back where it was. :)

Answer (score 1):

It now appears at the top of every page - move your mouse over the little down arrow to the left of your user name, and you'll see logout in there along with some other useful links.

Comment: Noticed that, thanks. The question was originally asked back when you had to navigate to the profile page of your main stack exchange user to find the logout link.